# Counting Principles problem people in line

Tags: combinatorics

You have 9 boys and 6 girls in a line. In how many ways can you arrange them so that no girls stand next to each other.

Answer (score 2):

First arrange the boys in $9!$ Then you have $10$ choice for girls, you should select $\binom {10}{6}$ and you can arrange girls in $6!$ different ways.

The answers is :$$ 9! \cdot \binom {10}{6} \cdot 6! $$

Comment: How does this prevent them from being beside each other?

Comment: @copper.hat When you arranged Boy's _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  like this you have 10 places for girl's between boys.

Comment: @Amir  I would add what you said in the comment to your answer since someone unfamiliar with the gap method would not know why you have ten locations in which to place the six girls.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a far more prosaic approach than Amir's:

The point is to show that one can obtain the result in a less 'ah-hah!'
way, except I need to use the 'stars & bars' result: The number of ways you can put $k$
identical objects into $n$ boxes is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$.

Suppose we assign the girls to positions first ($6!$ possibilities) and
then assign the boys.

The boys can go between the girls or on either of the 'outsides', so there
are $7$ places for them to go.

However, we need at least one boy between each girl so we will choose
the 'separating' boys first, there are $9!\cdots 5! = {9! \over 4!}$ ways
of allocating these fellows.

Now we can place the remaining $9-5 = 4$ boys to any of the $7$ places,
the above shows that there are $\binom{7+4-1}{4}=\binom{10}{4}$ ways of
doing this without regard to order, and each of these ways can be rearranged
in $4!$ ways so this results in $\binom{10}{4} 4! = {10! \over 6!}$ ways.

Combining the above gives
$$6! {9! \over 4!} {10! \over 6!} $$